# Can I use SQL to query/update data from XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml

Can I use SQL to query/update data from XML? I have some idea that it can be done by exporting the xmls to sql server, but can the xmls be updated using that?

Is there any other utility?

Comment: You can certainly import XML into SQL Server and "shred" them into relational data - but for the other way around, you really need a front-end, e.g. an application that grabs the data (as XML) from SQL Server and puts it into files. SQL Server isn't really designed to create new and update existing files - it's a database, after all - it handles data inside its storage

Answer (score 1):

An updategram is a data structure that you can use to express a change in the data. INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE commands are represented in an updategram by the difference of the image of the data before and the image of the data after a change.

One way to run an XML updategram is to save the updategram as a file, and then run the file in the URL as a template file.

you can refer the [document](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316018) in order how to do it.

Comment: I don’t think this answers the question. The linked article is about how to express an SQL _query_ in an “XML way”, not how to operate on XML _data_.